# What is the easiest and fastest way to change S3 bucket zone in the same region in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket count with some `TBs` of data in Ireland zone and I want to change it to Frankfurt zone in the same region (Europe) in order to make the `S3` data closer to my `EC2` instances which are in Frankfurt.

I saw many articles of how to change region for bucket but what about changing the zone.

Can you please suggest me the best way I can change my `S3` bucket zone (assuming that this has some `TB` of data so that I am not sure that the solution of Copy Paste it to a new bucket will be good).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `saw many articles of how to change region for bucket but what about changing the zone.` - Isn't region and your mentioned zone same thing?

Comment: @Justinas I am not sure, maybe for changing a zone there is an easier solution.
In AWS many times to change a zone can be much more easier than changing the region as I payed attention.

Comment: Well, I see that bucket only have region. To change that all I have found is copy-pasting to new bucket content, deleting old one and re-creating with new settings

Comment: @Justinas Does copy-pasting is fast for some TBs of data? (will it take less then hours?)

Comment: Have not tried such big data, but with CLI it takes quit fast. Any way, after deleting you will have to wait ~1h to be able to create bucket with same name again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are confusing Regions with Availability zones -  Ireland and Frakfurt are actually [2 different regions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html#concepts-available-regions) and S3 does not have the concept of availability zone as other AWS services.

You have to create a new bucket in Frankfurt region and upload your data to it - the simplest way is by using [`sync` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) provided by the AWS CLI.